# Generate a tar.gz stream on the fly with php

Tags: php, stream, tar, gzip

I want to send a larged packed file to a browser without temporary store the file on the local disk.

I want something like this:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);

header(...);
$streamer = new TarGZStream(PHP_STDOUT);

for($i;$i<100 && connection_status() == CONNECTION_NORMAL;$i++) {
  $fileContent = generateFileContent($i);
  ...
  $streamer->appendContent($fileContent,$filename1);

  $fileHandle = getAFileHandle($i);
  ...
  $streamer->appendFile($fileHandle ,$filename2);
}

cleanupFoo();
```

What I need:

- Streaming a tar.gz (or ZIP) to a stream handle or to stdout
- Adding some Data by a stream handle
- Adding some Data by an existing local file

How can I make the above scenario? What classes can be used? Is there a library for that?

Comment: Could this help? http://php.net/manual/en/phardata.buildfromiterator.php